# Display input field value dynamically using an ID

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to display an input field value on the screen, as it is been typed by the User.  Currently, I have a working prototype, but I couldn't figure out how to add an ID to the generic input field. Adding an ID would help to me target a specific input. I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="align-center">
    <input id="MyID" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Distributor ID">
    <span class="username"></span>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
$("input")
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("span").text("UserID" + value);
  })
  .keyup();
```

JSFiddle DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/rugf1kku/1/

Comment: value is getting displayed properly in your fiddle. what is your problem exactly?

Comment: what do you mean by `but I couldn't figure out how to add an ID`?

Comment: The input field is too generic, and I have a need to be more granular in my app when it comes to using input fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following thing in case you are asking how to write ID selector

```
$("#MyID")
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("span").text("UserID" + value);
  })
  .keyup();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly target specific input like below by getting Id from the element itself `$(this)[0].id` and apply `switch()` on for further segregation over input elements:

```
$("input")
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
   switch($(this)[0].id){
     case 'MyID':
         $("span").text("UserID" + value);
         break;
   }
  })
  .keyup();
```

Comment: This code worked well.  I'll keep in store for future use where I can use multiple input while specifying ID's. Thanks.